# How to call mongoose exported model function from express controller then return collection after update

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, mongoose, callback

### Current Controller (works fine)

I am updating a collection called `article` in my node `express` controller just fine. In my controller I am using the `mongoose` model function `findOne`, modifying the fields on the object that is found, calling `collection.save`, then redirecting to the newly edited article page with a success message. Here is that controller code:

```
// app/controllers/articles.controller.js
const Article = require('../models/article');

module.exports = {
  . . .
    // post to article edit
  processArticleEdit: (req, res, next) => {
    let article = new Article();
    var query = {
      slug: req.params.slug
    }
    var update = {
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body
    }

      // finding article, set new values, redirect to updated article
    Article.findOne(query, update, (err, article) => {
      article.title = update.title;
      article.body  = update.body;

      article.save((err) => {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}

        req.flash('notice', 'Article updated successfully');
        res.redirect('/articles/' + article.slug);
      });
    });
  },
  . . .
}
```

### Desired Model

But what if I want to write that same function not in the controller, but in the model instead? I have all of my other article `crud` operations written in the model, but for the `update`, as I can't get the collection back to my controller in order to redirect to the edited article.

Here is the code for the `model function` I would like, though it currently returns a slug attribute of `undefined`. Is there something awry with my model's `updateArticle` callback configuration?

```
// app/models/article.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

  // define schema for article collection
const articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  slug: { type: String, unique: true },
  body: String
});

  // pre-save middleware calls local function 'slugify()'
articleSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.title);
  next();
});

  // create the model
const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);

  // export the model
module.exports = Article;


  //
  // encapsulated model functions
  //

. . .

  // update single article
module.exports.updateArticle = function(query, update, callback) {
  Article.findOne(query, update, function (err, article) {
    article.title = update.title;
    article.body = update.body;
    article.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {res.send(err);}
    });
  });
}

. . .

  //
  // local model functions
  //

  // function creates string fit for human-frinedly url slug
function slugify(text) {
  return text.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
}
```

### Desired Controller

Here is the code for the `controller function` from which I would like to get back the updated article. Are we setting the returned collection properly? It says `undefined`:

```
// app/controllers/articles.controller.js
const Article = require('../models/article');

module.exports = {
  . . .
    // post to article edit
  processArticleEdit: (req, res, next) => {
    let article = new Article();
    var query = {
      slug: req.params.slug
    }
    var update = {
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body
    }
      // pass object to model function, then display updated article
    Article.updateArticle(query, update, (err, article) => {
      if (err) {res.send(err);}
      req.flash('notice', 'Article updated successfully');
      res.redirect('/articles/' + article.slug);
    });
  },
  . . .
}
```

### Current Router (works fine)

And finally the `router` which connects them and has no problems though I am providing it as reference:

```
// app/routes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const articlesController = require('./controllers/articles.controller');

module.exports = router;

  //
  // article routes
  //

. . .

   // post route for article edit
router.post('/articles/edit/:slug', articlesController.processArticleEdit);

  // get route for article show
router.get('/articles/:slug', articlesController.showArticle);

. . .
```

*(Side Note: We are calling `findOne` as we want to make use of the mongoose `pre-save middleware` which generates our human-friendly url slug. We could not find nor configure clean `pre-findOneAndUpdate middlware` schema function properly.)*

```
  // pre-findOneAndUpdate middleware calls local function 'slugify()'
articleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.title);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reading the Manual

I found a solution in the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating) which solves this problem when used in combination with callbacks, and some options:

> . . .
>
> This approach involves first retrieving the document from Mongo, then
>   issuing an update command (triggered by calling save). However, if we
>   don't need the document returned in our application and merely want to
>   update a property in the database directly, Model#update is right for
>   us:
>
> ```
> Tank.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, callback);
> ```
>
> If we do need the document returned in our application there is
>   another, often better, option:
>
> ```
> Tank.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, { new: true }, function (err, tank) {
>   if (err) return handleError(err);
>   res.send(tank);
> });
> ```
>
> The findAndUpdate/Remove static methods all make a change to at most
>   one document, and return it with just one call to the database. There
>   are several variations on the findAndModify theme. Read the API docs
>   for more detail.
>
> . . .

We need also to set the query option `new` equal to `true` in order to return the modified document in our `callback`, as described [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate):

> findOneAndUpdate()
>
> - Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the
>     callback. The query executes immediately if callback is passed.
>
> Available options
>
> - new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)
>
> . . .

### Devising a Solution

Here is the encapsulated model function which uses the `findOneAndUpdate` feature. It takes the record to find, and the new values to be saved on that record. Before it queries `mongodb`, it uses the incoming params to set an additional property for the record using our local model function `slugify()`. This query finds one record and updates it while making it available to the controller:

```
// app/models/article.js
  // update single article
module.exports.updateArticle = function(query, update, callback) {
    // set new slug variable using local model function
  var new_slug = slugify(update.title)
  Article.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: {slug: new_slug, title: update.title, body: update.body} }, { new: true }, callback, function (err, article) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}
```

The controller can now access the updated record as required:

```
// app/controllers/articles.controller.js
  // pass object to model function, generate redirect using the results
Article.updateArticle(query, update, (err, article) => {
  if (err) { res.send(err); }
  req.flash('notice', 'Article updated successfully');
  res.redirect('/articles/' + article.slug);
});
```

Apparently this feature was added in `mongoose 4.0`, and I am glad they did! Here is to encapsulated model functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted you question right maybe below might assist.

Best way to think of models is similar to object definitions in other languages. It provides a framework for each of the object it is going to instantiate. So when the controller gets a request, it uses the model definition and instantiate a new object then populate with the request data (as required).  Model can have a function property where some logic of the instance get manipulated.

But in your model, you are defining a new model object inside, then the program flow looses which object it is referring too.

In essence use the model definition to manipulate the object (properties and life-cycle). Then calling program (controllers or any other section) can create a new object based on an incoming request or situation to manipulate the newly create object life-cycle.